# Pandas Dataframe cannot find my first id_vars but I think it is in there. Any idea on how to fix this?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe I'm working with. When I try to melt using this code:

```
dataframe = pd.melt(dataframe, id_vars = ['Country Name'], var_name = 'Name')
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['Country Name']"
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: There is a whitespace. Try `dataframe.columns` to see if you can spot the whitespace. I bet it is spelled `Country Name ` or  ` Country Name` or  `Country  Name` instead of `Country Name`

Comment: Thanks, David!

Index(['Country Name', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American Samoa',
       'Andorra', 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina',
       ...
       'Virgin Islands (U.S.)', 'West Bank and Gaza', 'Yemen, Rep.', 'Zambia',
       'Zimbabwe', '', '', '',
       'Data from database: Worldwide Governance Indicators',
       'Last Updated: 11/07/2019'],
      dtype='object', name=0, length=220)

I'm not so sure there is whitespace within Country Name. Is that what you mean?

Comment: try restarting and clearing the output in your jupyter notebook. you are saving the object on itself, so you might have a different result saved.

Comment: I've tried... it doesn't work unfortunately. I'm really surprised cause it worked on other data.

Answer (score -1):

```
#The melt method needs to be called by the DateFrame object created
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':[1,2],'Name':['San Zhang', 'Si Li'],'Chinese':[80, 90],'Math':[80, 75]})
df
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars = ['Class', 'Name'],value_vars = ['Chinese', 'Math'],var_name = 'Subject', value_name = 'Grade')
df_melted
```

```
out:
    Class   Name    Subject Grade
0   1   san zhang   chinese 89
1   2   si li       chinese 93
2   1   san zhang    math   99
3   2   si li       math    89
```